# crontab -e yields: /var/spool/cron/: mkstemp: Permission denied

Tags: cron

I'm trying to set up a cron job under my user.  I run crontab -e, make my edits, and try to save and exit. I receive the following error message `/var/spool/cron/: mkstemp: Permission denied`.

Relevant output from ls -al /var/spool/cron/crontabs

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root crontab 4096 Nov  4 10:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Nov 19  2014 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 greg crontab   91 Nov  4 11:04 greg
-rw------- 1 root crontab 1231 Oct 29 16:18 root
```

I can directly edit the greg file and save that but I still can't seem to get the job to run, even if I restart cron after updating it.  What do I need to do to fix this problem?

The output from `ls -lha $(which crontab)` is:

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 36K Feb  8  2013 /usr/bin/crontab
```

The output from `groups greg` is:

```
greg : greg adm sudo crontab lpadmin sambashare
```

Comment: What does `ls -lha $(which crontab)` say? `crontab` should be setuid root becaue it will create temporary files in `/var/spool/cron`.

Comment: Does user greg belong to group cron?

Comment: @eyoung100 Yes, greg is part of the crontab group.  I'm assuming thats what you meant?

Comment: Have you logged out and back in since you added your user?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I think have posted the output of that ls command to the question.  I think it is set to root.

Comment: @eyoung100 No, didn't think to.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @eyoung100 That didn't seem to change anything.  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` has the wrong permissions. What operating system and version are you running? The package manager can likely fix things.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Ubuntu 14.04. What should the permissions be? And how would the package manager fix them?

Comment: It should be `drwx-wx--T`. And the `greg` file should be `-rw------- `.

Comment: I had just figured out the greg file bit from the syslog. I've fixed that.  Will work on the more general bit.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick So, I thought I had permissions down well enough to routinely do what I need to, but apparently not.  How do I set permissions to drwx-wx--T.  I tried some things but now the x are S and I can't get them to change even if I do something like chmod 000. How do things get stuck like that?

Comment: `sudo chmod 1730 /var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That still results in drws-ws--T.  I had been trying 1731, but I think I see why that was result in a small t at the end instead of a capital one.

Comment: Also, thank you everyone who has taken time to help.

Comment: `chmod a-s /var/spool/cron/crontabs` to get rid of the s bits.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Also, that chmod 1730 seems to have made the original `mkstemp: Permission denied` error disappear.  If you make an actual answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: Do you know how the directory got the wrong perms in the first place? If somebody did a `chmod -R 755 /var`, for instance, you may have more things to worry about.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I don't know exactly.  I think something like that may have happened at some point and been somewhat fixed.  The machine does seem to do most of whats required of it but setting up this cronjob has been a nightmare of previously undiscovered by me errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will fix your immediate problem:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=wx,o=t /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

But, if you can download packages, a more robust way to fix this is to use `apt-get` to reinstall the appropriate package:

```
root@ubuntu# dpkg-query -S /var/spool/cron/crontabs
cron: /var/spool/cron/crontabs
root@ubuntu# apt-get install --reinstall cron
```

after first making sure any local changes you've made to `/etc/init/cron.conf`, `/etc/default/cron`, etc. are copied somewhere and then reapplied.

Answer (score 4):

The solution mentioned by Mark Plotnick didn't work for me, however after adding my user to the `crontab` group it worked:

```
sudo adduser myname crontab
```

You'll need to logout and login again for this change to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04:

```
crontab ~/admin/scripts/crontab.txt
```

> /var/spool/cron/: mkstemp: Permission denied

```
$ ls -lha $(which crontab)
```

> -rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 39K Mar 23  2022 /usr/bin/crontab

```
~$ ls -lha /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

> ls: cannot open directory '/var/spool/cron/crontabs': Permission denied

```
~$ sudo ls -lha /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

> total 8.0K
>
> drwx-wx--T 2 root systemd-journal 4.0K Mar  2  2023 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root            4.0K Jul 22 09:48 ..

So we need 2 groups for user executing in order to get privileges:

```
sudo usermod -a -G systemd-journal <user>
sudo usermod -a -G systemd-journal <user>
```

Logoff and logon again with user ...

```
crontab ~/admin/scripts/crontab.txt

crontab -l
```

> 0 */1 * * * ~/admin/scripts/elasticsearch_flush.sh > /dev/null 2>&1